# Regex always matches last group clause

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

`AC7640  Montreal Trudeau (YUL)  La Guardia/New York (LGA)  E75  Business (P)  Confirmed`

I want it to match `AC`, `7640`, `YUL` and `LGA`

But I also want to match if last airport doesn't exist for instance:

`AC7640  Montreal Trudeau (YUL)  E75  Business (P)  Confirmed`

`AC`, `7640` and `YUL`

I came up with this regex:
`([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9]{1,4})(?:.*?\(([A-Z]{3})\)){1,2}`

The problem is that it only matches 1 airport on both strings

I'm using python flavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unroll" the pattern since the repeated  capturing groups only store the last occurrence:

```
^([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9]{1,4}).*?\(([A-Z]{3})\)(?:.*?\(([A-Z]{3})\))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/51Beyr/4). Also, note that the last part, `(?:.*?\(([A-Z]{3})\))?`, is enclosed with an optional non-capturing group, so that it could match 1 or 0 occurrences. `^` at the start makes the regex engine to search from the beginning of the string only.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])` - Group 1: two uppercase letters or an upppercase letter and a digit or a digit and an uppercase letter

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `([0-9]{1,4})`  - Group 2: one to four digits
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `\(` - a `(`
- `([A-Z]{3})` - Group 3: three uppercase letters
- `\)` - `)`
- `(?:.*?\(([A-Z]{3})\))?` - a non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 (*optional*) occurrences of:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first ....
  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `([A-Z]{3})` - Group 4:  three uppercase letters
  - `\)` - a `)`.

Comment: I love it, small correction though `([A-Z]{1,3})` should be `([A-Z]{3})` in both cases

Comment: Maybe, but I saw the airport codes can be 1 char long. Well, that can be adapted.

Comment: Aha, I got that bit now. In the second case, the `P` should not be returned.